# Is cordova supporting ES6 and/or Angular2?

Tags: cordova, ecmascript-6, angular

I want to create mobile app by using phonegap and I want to use Angular2 that works with ES6. I can't find any information about that on they official website.
I want to know is it will work or no?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Updated answer 2021

If you're targeting [Android 4.4 (or lower) you can't use ES6](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/905#issuecomment-577917700) because it's not supported unless you use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to compile your code (see below). From [Android 5.0 the webview is independent from the OS](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/webview/overview/) and it's updated seperately from the OS, so you can use ES6 directly.

You can also check your target OS/browser ES6 support on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/es6).

### Original answer

ECMAScript 6 support doesn't depend on Cordova, is a Webview issue.

If the native Webview where the app will be executed support ES6, you app will be work nice, otherwise doesn't.

Since the ES6 specification was finally [approved on June 17 of this year (2015)](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/Publication%20of%20ECMA-262%206th%20edition.htm), the actual support for ES6 of mobile Webview is missing or incomplete.

To run ECMAScript 6 applications today you can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or [Traceur compiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler), that "*compile*" your code from ES6 to ES5. This is also the approach used in [Angular 2 quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) (see the traceur import in section "*6. Declare the HTML*").

So, why don't you try [an Angular 2 generator that include traceur](https://github.com/swirlycheetah/generator-angular2) or a [web app generator with babel](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp)? If you are new to the tools involved, I suggest you to start learning grunt/gulp/bower/yo.

Comment: There is no EC. It's abbreviated ES!

Comment: Thank you Bergi, it was a very dummy typo, fixed! :)

Comment: What is the status after three years now?